# How to load background-images from /src folder that are svgs

Tags: reactjs, svg

I'm making a custom React dropdown component and am trying to use custom SVGs as background images based on the selected value. Locally, they are rendered perfectly but when building a sandbox to test my branch I get 405 errors.

Initially, my images were in /public but even when moving to /src... I am still getting 405s.

Both relative + absolute paths do not work.
`background-image: url('../images/lock.svg');`
`background-image: url('/images/lock.svg');`

Comment: Same here. That is why It is better to make a utils folder inside the src. If you are using images in CSS It is better to have an extra folder called assets inside the public.

Comment: have you tried '~/images/lock.svg'. Additionally with SVGs it may be advantageous to create individual components and pass them in that way if you need to manipulate them at all.